# RSS Feed has no styles in chrome - function to add one?

Tags: functions, rss

This is a really bizarre problem. For some reason Chrome does not have any RSS feed formatting?

Where as most other browsers do!

So it seems from I read online that I have to create my own style sheet for it :/

That's fine, but how can I add my RSS stylesheet to my wordpress RSS feed without manipulating the core files.

Is there a function that will allow me to add this style sheet?

Thanks for any tips :-)

Comment: btw: set up a username :)

Comment: Done........ ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a problem you really need to solve. Any regular Chrome user knows this is how Chrome (doesn't) handle RSS.

That said, you can provide a custom feed template. see [Customizing Your Feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds#Customizing_Your_Feeds) in Codex.

Comment: Thank you @Milo - I always get worried if things are not same accross all browsers, and since I've moved to chrome, I have only just noticed this RSS issue. But thanks for the codex link.